# Dependence of resistance of conductor on inertial frame

Tags: electromagnetism

Does the resistance of a conductor depend on an inertial frame?

What is the experimental and the theoretical evidences for that?

Comment: Do you mean in it's own frame of reference?

Comment: @AdrianHoward:   Assume we measure the resistance of a conductor either when it is at rest on the Earth (here I consider the frame related to the Earth to be inertial), or at rest with respect to a moving train. Do we get the same result?

Comment: It will be the same in it's own frame of reference

Comment: @AdrianHoward : Why? Is it experimental fact? Is there theoretical argument? Any references? Thank you.

Comment: @AdrianHoward  *its

Comment: Hi, perhaps you could show us where you've looked for relevant information, and what you found or didn't find that is unclear to you.

Comment: @MKO It is one of Einstein's postulates of relativity that all frames of reference are equally valid. There is no absolute frame of reference.

Comment: @AdrianHoward : Right, there is no absolute frame.  But may be there is no absolute value of resistance.